# Unity Prefab with extended Functionality

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to dye a certain part of a prefab in my code.

The issue: The user should be able to use any prefab. In the prefab there should be described what the certain part is (maybe by using a MonoBehaviour?).

It is not needed that really just a part of a single prefab is dyed.
If I need to use a nested prefab in which I dye a complete child-prefab of the main prefab, it is fine too.

Do you have an idea how to do so?
I think it doesn't make a change but for the record:
I use the latest version of Unity Entities 1.0.